# Как написать скрипт , который реагирует на изменение значения input который идёт с базы MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Помогите пожалуста реально очень надо!

Имеется следующая база данных, где в колонке `input` все значения зашифрованы в `base64`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот её расшифрованный вариант:

```html
{
  "height": {
    "name": "Максимальна висота",
    "text": {
      "ua": "Максимальна висота"
    },
    "value_start": 2000,
    "value_max": 2600,
    "value_min": 1800,
    "help": {
      "ua": "Максимальна висота"
    }
  },
  "widtha": {
    "name": "Максимальна ширина",
    "text": {
      "ua": "Максимальна ширина"
    },
    "value_start": 1200,
    "value_max": 1600,
    "value_min": 1000,
    "help": {
      "ua": "Максимальна ширина"
    }
  },
  "width": {
    "name": "Мінімальна ширина",
    "text": {
      "ua": "Мінімальна ширина"
    },
    "value_start": 900,
    "value_max": 1500,
    "value_min": 700,
    "help": {
      "ua": "Мінімальна ширина"
    }
  }
}
```

После чего я создаю вывод из базы данных:

```html
$input = '';
        $input_arr = json_decode($calc_rez['input'],true);
        foreach($input_arr as $input_one_id => $input_one_value) {
            if (isset($input_one_value['help'])) {
                $help = 'data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="'.base64_decode($input_one_value['help'][$_SESSION['LANG']]).'"';
            } else if (isset($input_one_value['help_page'])) {
                $help = 'onClick="showPopHelp('.$input_one_value['help_page'].')"';
            } else {$help = '';}
            
            $input .= '
                <div class="box">
                    <input name="input-'.$input_one_id.'" type="number" value="'.$input_one_value['value_start'].'" data-max="'.$input_one_value['value_max'].'" data-min="'.$input_one_value['value_min'].'" />
                    <label>'.base64_decode($input_one_value['text'][$_SESSION['LANG']]).'</label>
                    <i class="fa fa-question-circle" '.$help.'></i>
                </div>
            ';
            
            $div.='
                <div id="input-'.$input_one_id.'" class="input-'.$input_one_id.'">'.$input_one_value['value_start'].'</div>
            ';
        }
```

Тут я вывожу то, что получилось из кода выше:

```html
<form class="data">
                    <div class="input">
                        {$input}
                    </div>
<div class="col-md-7 scheme">
                        <div class="config-text">
                            {$div}
                        </div>
                        <img class="col-md-7 scheme" src="/upload-files/calc/{$calc_rez['cat_id']}/scheme.png" style="margin-bottom: 30px;" />
                    </div>
```

И мне надо, чтобы значение при вводе в поле выводились на картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если присмотреться, в базе данных нет одинаковых значений `input`.

Мне также необходимо, чтобы для каждого типа кабинок всё работало индивидуально.

У меня получилось вытащить из базы значение, которое изначально присвоено  `input`

Я сделал так, чтобы они выводились и на картинку, но мне ещё надо сделать так, чтобы при изменении значения оно менялось и на картинке.

А это мини скрипт, который работает для обновления числа. Но он работает криво, помогите или со скриптом, или может, возможно как-то по другому это сделать?

```js
 // Получаем все элементы с атрибутом name по имени
            const displayElements = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="display"]');
            const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="input-"]');
    
            // Добавляем обработчик событий для каждого введенного поля
            inputElements.forEach((inputElement, index) => {
                inputElement.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
                    const inputValue = inputElement.value;
                    // Находим подходящий элемент вывода по индексу и обновляем его текст
                    if (index < displayElements.length) {
                        displayElements[index].textContent = inputValue;
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
<div>
            <div type="number"><p name="display" class="1">2000</p> </div>
            <div type="number"><p name="display" class="2">2000</p> </div>
            <div type="number"><p name="display" class="3">2000</p> </div>
        </div>
        <div><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="input-height1"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="input-esf2"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="input-height2"><br><br>
        </div>
```

Тут я делал пример, но он мне не особо подходит, хоть я и был почти у цели. Не подходит он мне потому, что когда я просто на стрелочке сделаю +1 значение, то оно не выведется на экран, а если в `input` вписать вручную, то оно сразу сработает. Или, например, там есть значение 2000, если я удалю из него два нуля и напишу 92 - должно вывести 2092, а выводит 92 просто!

Comment: ваш вопрос не имеет отношения к РНР или mysql. скрипт который реагирует на измененеи инпута, пишется на яваскрипте. поэтому из вопроса надо убрать весь РНР код, и показать только HTML

Comment: Тк может можно это решить и через сервер.

Comment: Спроси у своего любимого ГПТ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение даной проблемы!

```js
<script>
                            // Очікувати завершення завантаження сторінки
                            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                                // Отримати всі елементи вводу і виводу
                                const displayElements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="display"]');
                                const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="input-"]');

                                // Оновити значення виводу при завантаженні сторінки
                                inputElements.forEach((inputElement, index) => {
                                    const inputValue = inputElement.value;
                                    if (index < displayElements.length) {
                                        displayElements[index].textContent = inputValue;
                                    }
                                });

                                // Додати обробник подій для кожного елемента вводу
                                inputElements.forEach((inputElement, index) => {
                                    inputElement.addEventListener('input', function() {
                                        const inputValue = inputElement.value;
                                        if (index < displayElements.length) {
                                            displayElements[index].textContent = inputValue;
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
```